# Global SCSS style is no longer loaded in Storybook with Angular 12

Tags: webpack, sass, storybook, angular12

I am migrating a library to use Angular and Material 12 (currently in version 10), and Storybook is used to expose the various components of this library. To do so, I upgraded  Angular and Material to version 12 with the Angular Update Guide, Storybook to version 6.3 with `npx sb upgrade` and I followed the steps described [here](https://github.com/storybookjs/storybook/blob/next/MIGRATION.md#from-version-62x-to-630) to fully migrate Storybook and use webpack5.

Unfortunately, the **base.scss** file previously included globally in the rendering of stories is no longer included (stories are now without any CSS). This base.scss file is included in a Typescript file with:

`import '!style-loader!css-loader!sass-loader!./base.scss';`

**With Storybook 6.3 and Angular 10, everything works perfectly.**

To fix that, I tried to add this configuration in **main.js**, as it is described in the documentation:

```js
webpackFinal: async (config, { configType }) => {
    config.module.rules.push({
      test: /\.scss$/,
      use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'sass-loader'],
      include: path.resolve(__dirname, '../'),
    });
    return config;
  }
```

But I got this error for each of my story:

```js
SassError: SassError: expected "{".
  ╷
1 │ import api from "!../../../../node_modules/style-loader/dist/runtime/injectStylesIntoStyleTag.js";
  │                                                                                                  ^
  ╵
  src\stories\utils\trademarks-format\example-utils-trademarks-format.component.scss 1:98  root stylesheet
    at Object.callback (D:\bmx\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\node_modules\sass-loader\dist\index.js:54:16)
    at Worker.<anonymous> (D:\bmx\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\src\sass\sass-service.js:134:25)
    at Worker.emit (events.js:400:28)
    at MessagePort.<anonymous> (internal/worker.js:236:53)
    at MessagePort.[nodejs.internal.kHybridDispatch] (internal/event_target.js:399:24)
    at MessagePort.exports.emitMessage (internal/per_context/messageport.js:18:26)
```

I have removed `node-sass` that was previously installed, I have added `sass-loader`, `css-loader`, `sass` and `style-loader` in dev dependencies and I tried to add the `@storybook/preset-scss` addon without the custom webpack configuration but it didn't work. I also tried [this solution](https://github.com/storybookjs/storybook/issues/11052#issuecomment-650618938) but it didn't work either.

I saw [here](https://github.com/storybookjs/presets/issues/195#issuecomment-814408891) that it could be an issue with sass-loader in version greater than 10 so I have choosed the 10.1.1 version but I have the impression that the devkit dependency of Angular 12 imports sass-loader in its version 12. **Would there be a conflict there?** If so, I don't know how to force Angular 12 to use version 10 of sass-loader.

I would be really happy to have a lead that could solve my problem because it's been several days since I feel like I tried everything...

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have answered my question. In fact there was no need to change the webpack configuration for my case. It was enough to add the `@storybook/preset-scss` addon.

The problem was described [here](https://github.com/storybookjs/storybook/issues/15855). I needed to **downgrade Angular to 12.1 version**. I was in 12.2.

Hopefully this helps someone.

Answer (score 3):

In the latest version of Angular (13), there is a much simpler way of adding your global styles to your storybook. Just add your stylesheets to your **storybook-architekt** in your angular.json, under **your-project** > **(build-)storybook** > **options** > **styles**.

As importing the stylesheets in *.storybook/main.js* is no longer supported, you can remove it and instead add the stylesheets like shown below.

angular.json:

```json
"your-project": {
  ...
  "storybook": {
      "builder": "@storybook/angular:start-storybook",
      "options": {
          ...
          "projectBuildConfig": "your-lib:build-storybook",
          "styles": [
              "path-to-the-stylesheet/styles.scss",
              "path-to-the-stylesheet/your-theme.scss"
          ],
          ...
      },
      ...
  
    },
    ...
}
```

You can find this information in the [migration-guide](https://github.com/storybookjs/storybook/blob/next/MIGRATION.md#64-angular-changes) of storybook.